# I accidently hit a key combo and it messed up my view

Tags: 3d-view

My hands accidentally fumbled over the keyboard and the 3d view ended up with a dark volume that extends out forever from a point. Anything outside that view is hidden. I am unable to recover the file for some reason and may of just lost about 20 hours of work as I am unable to find out what I did.[image]

Comment: The shortcut to add that to a scene is Alt+B, same as to remove it

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:
File > Load Factory Settings.

Of course, this will reset any custom settings you set up.

I don't know what that thing is. Kinda looks like a lamp. Try alt+H to un-hide everything? Or check other layers?

Sorry about your lost work. Did you check .blend1 files?

Comment: Thankfully a friend told me there's a thing called Append that lets me recover the file's objects. I still have no idea what key combo caused it since it's per file, not view setting. So I think it's a tool of sorts.